# How to populate a few rectangle styles in a Combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, rectangles

I have a combobox and there is a little Template in XAML like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboStyles" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="15" Width="Auto">
                <!-- Don't know what to do here. -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And I want to populate a few rectangles in there with different border styles like dashed and dotted. Better is it to populate it from the code behind in C#.

Comment: You can give that `StackPanel` a name (`x:Name`) and then reference once template is loaded ([click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx)).

Comment: What do the border styles depend o? A property on the bound collections' items?

Comment: That doesn't help so far. Do you have a little snippet for me to do that so? I don't get it.

Comment: You can select a style and this style will applied to another control.

Comment: Do you want different rectangles to be shown?

Comment: Yes, with different border styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboStyles" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="100">
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="5" Width="50" Height="50" StrokeDashArray="5" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Blue" Margin="5" Width="50" Height="50" StrokeDashArray="5" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Green" Margin="5" Width="50" Height="50" StrokeDashArray="5" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Red" Margin="5" Width="50"  Height="50" StrokeDashArray="5" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>
    </ComboBox>
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: This helps partially, but I want rectangles with dashed borders.